# Suppose that $A$ is a set such that $|A| = m$. What is $| \{ X \subseteq \mathcal{P}(A) : |X| \le 1 \} |$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

> Suppose that $A$ is a set such that $|A| = m$. What
>   is $| \{ X \subseteq \mathcal{P}(A) : |X| \le 1 \} |$?

I think that $| \{ X \subseteq \mathcal{P}(A) : |X| \le 1 \} | = | \mathcal{P}(A) | = 2^m$.

The set of all $X \subseteq \mathcal{P}$ is going to have more elements than $\mathcal{P}$. However, since we have the condition $|X| \le 1$, the set of all $X \subseteq \mathcal{P}$ will just be all of the elements in $\mathcal{P}$.

I would appreciate it if people could please review my solution and reasoning.

Comment: Doesn't $|X|\le1$ mean that the cardinality of $X$ is less than or equal to 1?

Comment: @saulspatz Yes.

Comment: @ChristianF You're right, that was an error.

Comment: Hold the phone, I'm the one who misread the question.  We're looking at subsets of the power set, I thought it said **elements**.  So you are very close to being correct.  You overlooked the empty subset of the power set.

Comment: @saulspatz Yes, I just deleted my response and was about to post another, haha. Indeed, I think my interpretation was correct. :)

Comment: But wouldn't that still be the same as $| \mathcal{P}(A) |$? $| \mathcal{P}(A) |$ would have the empty set. $X$ wouldn't have the empty set, but it would have a set containing the empty set $\{ \emptyset \}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question asks for the number of subsets of $\mathcal{P}(A)$ that are of cardinality $\le 1$.  For any set $S$ the only subset of cardinality $0$ is the empty set, and there is one subset of cardinality $1$ for every $s\in S$ namely $\{s\}$.  So the cardinality would be $|S|+1$.

Your answer is close to being correct.  You just missed the empty set.  The correct answer is $2^m+1.$

As for your last comment, yes $\emptyset\in\mathcal P(A)$.  So both $\emptyset$ and $\{\emptyset\}$ are subsets of $\mathcal P(A).$

Comment: Hmm. The empty set has cardinality $0$, but what about a set containing the empty set? Wouldn't we have $X = \{ \emptyset \}$ as the one with the empty set? In which case, would *this* have cardinality 1?

Comment: Your answer is close to being correct. You just missed the notation for the cardinality of $A$ is $m$. The correct answer is $2^m+1$.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Thanks.

Comment: Hold on, isn't only $\emptyset \in \mathcal{P}(A)$?

Comment: @ThePointer: It's both an element and a subset.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Oh, right. Yes, you're right.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1610224/what-is-the-cardinality-of-the-set-of-the-empty-set "$A = \{\emptyset\}$  is a set containing one element. That element is itself also a set, but this is irrelevant."

Comment: Let $A = \{ 1, 2 \}$. Therefore, $\mathcal{P}(A) = \{ \{ 1 \}, \{ 2 \}, \{ 1, 2 \}, \emptyset \}$. So we have $X = \{ \{ 1 \} \}, \{ \{ 2 \} \}, \{ \{ 1, 2 \} \}, \{\ \emptyset \} $; that's 4 elements?

Comment: No, you've left out $\emptyset$.  Perhaps you don't realize that $\emptyset \ne \{\emptyset\}$

Comment: Ohhhh, it's $\le 1$, so $\emptyset$ itself also counts!

Comment: Ok, I now understand why it's $2^m + 1$. Thanks for the help!

Comment: It was my pleasure.